# Use curses with colorama

Tags: python, python-curses, colorama

Is it possible to use curses with colorama? Here is my code, it prints the escape sequences:

```
from curses import wrapper
import colorama

STYLE = colorama.Fore.GREEN + colorama.Back.BLUE
TITLE = STYLE + 'Current terminal size:'
HEIGHT_STRING = STYLE + 'Screen height: {}\n'
WIDTH_STRING = STYLE + 'Screen width:  {}\n'
STR_LEN = 18


def main(stdscr):

    colorama.init()
    stdscr.clear()

    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    y = height//2 - 2
    x = width//2 - STR_LEN//2

    stdscr.addstr(y - 2, x, TITLE)
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, HEIGHT_STRING.format(height))
    stdscr.addstr(y + 1, x, WIDTH_STRING.format(width))

    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey(y + 2, x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wrapper(main)
```

I know that curses can't be used on Windows, just wondering if this is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the description of [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), no (it uses hardcoded escape sequences), doesn't have a method for output in other forms.

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html), [UniCurses](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses) should work (on Windows).  That's using PDCurses.  ncurses itself works for Windows well enough, there being packages for it in [MSYS2](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/ncurses) and Cygwin.